# Parcel incorrectly rewrites media queries

Tags: css, sass, parceljs

I am currently using parcel 2.8.3 and @parcel/transformer-sass 2.8.3 and I am having some issues with the way it rewrites media queries. On my previous project where I used parcel as well I had no such issues everything was the way it should be.

Here's the SASS file:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  h1 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

and here's the CSS output:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}

@media only screen and (width <= 40em) {
  h1 {
    color: #00f;
  }
}
```

As you can see the media query in the CSS file has been changed from max-width to width <= 40em which does not work when viewed on an actual mobile phone.

If I use the package-lock.json and package.json which I copied from a project from 1 month ago, the media query gets rewritten as it should. Upon running `npm i parcel & npm i @parcel/transformer-sass` for my new project as show above, when I launch the project all of the media queries are changed as shown in the 2nd code block. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to extend the browserslist. Add the following to your package.json:

```
"browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 3 versions, not dead"
```

This will extend the supported browsers and should make sure this wont be overwritten and older safari can deal with.

Comment: Fixed my issue as well, my media queries were just completely gone while using parcel@2.9.3 and parcel/transformer-sass@2.9.3. This messed up the complete UI where you were resizing elements.