# CSS media (max-width) querie not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, parcel

My website does not respond to @media in Safari. It works fully in Chrome, but nothing happens when I use Safari. I have only tested Chrome and Safari, so I don't know if other browsers also struggle.

I noticed this after I launched my website: alexanderrubino.com.

I have broken down/removed all of the unnecessary code to find the problem. This includes all CSS files, JavaScript Files and even all of the HTML code, so that I am simply just trying to change the background-color of the body. The new code works in Chrome, but not Safari.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alexander Rubino</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Frontend/WordPress/App Developers Portfolio, Alexander Rubino. Made with Three.js."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, frontend, three.js, developer, arcade, room">
    <meta name="author" content="Alexander Rubino">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/public/images/me.webp">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
            * {
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my package.json file if that effects anything:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "vercel --prod",
    "vercel-build": "parcel build index.html"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^3.9.1",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "static": "^2.0.0",
    "three": "^0.136.0",
    "vercel": "^23.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^4.1.11",
    "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of the solutions online, but none of them seem to fix my problem. Hope you can help

Comment: I do not see the problem on Safari IOS on an iPad. ie the background turns light blue. What device are you on?

Comment: I am using my MacBook and also my Iphone 11, which both does not work

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it really does show the problem. I can only think it is created by a library/package you are using because the pure HTML/CSS you have given works fine.

Comment: It does work when I insert the code in a codepen. Which means that it is probably parcel that breaks it, I just don't get why.

Comment: What do you see when you inpect through your browser's devtools? That should show you exactly what, and from where, CSS is being applied.

Comment: It actually rewrites the CSS, which does not work with Safari apparently.
So my CSS Code gets rewritten to:

@media screen and (width <= 1600px) {
  * {
    background-color: #add8e6 !important;
  }
}

It is the same problem as this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166605/parcel-incorrectly-rewrites-media-queries

But I can't make their solution work for me

Comment: So is it that !important that does it?

Comment: No. It looks the same with or without !important

Comment: What version of Safari are you on because it seems that <= sort of syntax was not introduced until Safari 16.4. Oh, just noticed you are on 16.5 so that theory is blown.

Comment: I have set up a codesandbox, which only makes me more confused. The code works in the sandbox, but when I copy the exact code into VSCode, it doesn't work. Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-morse-54hpwr?file=/index.html

Comment: Oh dear! I’m l stuck. Maybe the only thing is to plod through the code produced by the sandbox comparing it with that produced by VSCode. Sometimes it’s things like meta or document tags, but I can’t see that’s it here.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I can only think of two problems that could occur

1. your version of Safari is not compatible with the max-width property.
2. some of your dependencies override this CSS style, try to use !important

I hope I could help you with this

Comment: My Safari version on my MacBook is 16.5, which shouldn't be a problem. The !important tag did not work. Is there another way to register when a user is on the phone, or smaller device without max-width?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe you can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent,
For some examples: https://stackdiary.com/detect-mobile-browser-javascript/
I hope this will help you, it is supported by Safari