# Google Chrome (Windows): CSS media queries ignored/removed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

A colleague has a strange problem I’ve never encountered before. He uses Chrome on Windows, and on one website, the rendering of the site looks as if all CSS rules based on media queries were absent. But even better, mq-based styles aren’t even visible in the developer tools:

[image: Styles in dev tools]

Other Chrome users (Windows or Mac) don’t have this problem, and that colleague does not have this problem when using Firefox. There are no extensions in the colleague’s Chrome and I have ensured the CSS file loaded is exactly the correct one. CSS is hosted on the same host as the website and bundled via Parcel. The problem occurs on a subdomain of our company website, and Chrome renders other subdomains of the same domain (including media queries, of course) normally.

I am completely baffled and have no idea what might be the cause. Searching the web for other users with the same phenomenon, I didn’t find anything relevant, only myriads of common media-query-related problems …

Any ideas?

Comment: I have never seen a `>=` in a media query and can't even find it in the MDN docs as a thing, so maybe it's that? Don't you have `max-width` for that feature and does it fix it?

Comment: @somethinghere it's in the media query spec 4. https://caniuse.com/css-media-range-syntax. The only thing I can suspect, is if the media query doesn't show in the colleague's dev tools, is that Chrome is somehow way out of date. OP, this may be a ridiculous question, but do other websites show `media-queries` in your colleague's dev tools?

Comment: @somethinghere: we got it, thanks for your help. It is indeed the MQ syntax, which we were able to track down using a simple test page. Parcel (or rather other dependencies used by Parcel) in recent versions decided to optimize the MQ – with a syntax which requires Chrome ≥ v104. That colleague has v103, as on his machine, for whatever reason, updates are forbidden (which is obviously a dump idea for security reasons, and pretty surprising, as we use device management). So basically it comes down to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76166605/4715679

Comment: @disinfor: and thanks also to you (SO doesn’t let me mention two users in one post …)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a combination of Parcel “optimizing” the media queries from `min-width` to `width: >=` and a machine with disabled Chrome updates and hence a pretty dated Chrome version. And it looks like Chrome suppresses CSS rules in the dev tools if it doesn’t understand the MQ syntax. (Also see comments.)